# find the top 5 destinations for each month by total number of flights

Tags: r

I am finding the top 5 destinations for each month by total number of flights library(nycflights13), but I am confused to filter the top 5 dest.

```
flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(air_time)) %>% 
  group_by(dest, month) %>% 
  mutate(real_flights = sum(air_time >= 0, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  summarise(total_flights = sum(real_flights)) %>% 
  arrange(month, desc(total_flights))
```

Comment: Take a look at the online doc for `slice_max()`. Having two columns named `flights_total` and `total_flights` is confusing! Welcome to SO.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to know the relative positions of each one and not drop others you could create a rank column using either rank or dense_rank.